# Toledo invariant of the associated vector bundle of a surface bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, complex-geometry

Given a (smooth but not holomorphic) surface bundle over surface $S_g\to X\to S_h$, then there are two associated vector bundles $H^1(S_g,\mathbb C)\to E\to S_h$ and $H^{1,0}(S_g,\mathbb C)\to E_1\to S_h$, s.t. the Toledo invariant of $E$ is $\deg{E_1}$.

I think I know why we have the vector bundle $H^{1,0}(S_g,\mathbb C)\to E_1\to S_h$, but I am not sure why we have $H^1(S_g,\mathbb C)\to E\to S_h$. Also, by [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605656.pdf), we can define the Toledo invariant from a surface group representation $\rho:\pi_1(S_h)\to G$ to be $\langle \rho^*(K_G),[S_h]\rangle$. Here, we can always construct such a representation $\rho:\pi_1(S_h)\to \text{SL}(2g,\mathbb R)$ from the monodromy representation of the initial surface bundle. But I am not sure what the Toledo invariant of $E$ is and if the representation $\rho:\pi_1(S_h)\to \text{SL}(2g,\mathbb R)$ is related to the Toledo invariant of $E$. Moreover, why is the Toledo invariant of $E$ $\deg{E_1}$? I am not an expert in this area and I would be very grateful if someone could provide an explanation.